# Thunkable x firebase: resultado randômico

Tags: firebase

Montei um bloco que sobe imagem pro Firebase e funciona.
Agora preciso montar um bloco que traga uma destas de forma randômica.
Alguma luz, por favor?

Comment: As imagens estão sendo salvas no storage? existe alguma referencia a elas no database? Se existir a key de cada imagem do storage no database basta pegar aleatoriamente uma das keys.